# Glue vs spring, the approach

Tags: terminology, spring, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, gluons

Why does quantum mechanics use the term "glue" instead of "spring"? Is the strong force wchich keeps quarks together so different from the behavior of springs that they must have a separate name? They both work in low range.

We have a well-described mechanics of elastic bodies, mainly in 2D, but for a reasonable number of vertices it should be easily scalable with tensors to as many dimensions as needed

Comment: It's just words used as an image, neither has any "technical" value. You'll probably find your answer in the story of how the word "gluon" came to be. This should be posted in the [History of science site](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know that such exists